# Extract parts of inputs strings

Tags: xslt

I am trying to extract equipment names from strings and would like if someone could help me find a good way to do this.

My input string can either contain 1 or 2 equipment names, consisting of EQ followed 1 to 3 digits, for example :

```
LocationEQ3Suffix
LocationEQ5EQ8Suffix
```

So in the first instance I would need 'EQ3' and in the second instance I would need 'EQ5' and 'EQ8'.
I need the output to be in a text format, for example :

```
SomeText.EQ3
SomeText.EQ5
SomeText.EQ8
```

I was thinking there might be a way to do this with xsl:analyze-string and a regex like EQ[0-9]{1,3}.

Any help is appreciated.

I started something like this, but I don't think it's the right approach.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">


  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="input" select="'LocationEQ3EQ4Funct'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- Case with 2 EQ -->
        <xsl:when test="matches($input, 'EQ[0-9]{1,3}EQ[0-9]{1,3}')">
            <xsl:value-of select="$input"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- Case with 1 EQ -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to use `xsl:analyze-string` but you're not.

An implementation using it would look something like:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="input-string" regex="EQ\d{{1,3}}">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:text>SomeText.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9Hk1a

Comment: Thanks. I had misread the standard and thought I had to use regex-group() to get the results. Why are double curly-braces required ({{1,3}} instead of {1,3}) in the RegEx?

Comment: Because curly braces are used for attribute value templates.